# How to find the pixels of any text on the screen?

Tags: c#, automation

I want to make a simple automation program. There is a program currently in use. The program does not support "System.Windows.Automation" and it is not a program I wrote. There are regular transactions. I want to automate these processes. If the program is open and used on the screen as desired, I can direct the mouse to the relevant pixel and click. I can do this as follows. However, situations such as changing the screen resolution and the program not being in maximized mode disrupt my downstream operations. Because the following event is a process of going to a specific pixel and clicking.

What I want to do is find the button that says "Print" on the screen and click it, regardless of its position. How can I find where the "Print" text is on the screen?

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, int dx, int dy, uint dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetCursorPos(int x, int y);

    public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
    public const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
```

If I want to write somewhere, I can write as follows.

```
 SendKeys.SendWait("Text");
```

Summary: My goal is to write the text I want into the textbox in a different program and click the "Print" button. This includes multiple monitors with different resolutions. Enabling the program to run regardless of its current position on the screen.

Thank you for your answers.

Edit: I can take a screenshot with Tesseract and check whether there is a relevant text or not, but I cannot find which pixel the relevant text is on.

Comment: Typically this is done by finding the control for the function and send the proper Windows Message for a click to that. Looking for the text is in many ways problematic. It might be multiple times on the screen in different contexts meaning somethimg different or are localized.

Comment: How can I find out which Windows Message I should send?

Comment: Monitor the application and what it uses while you do the needed steps manually. For example a Visual Studio installation contains somewhere a tool called Spy++ that can do that but there are others presumably easier to use out there.

Comment: I understand that you are suggesting that I use a 3rd party program to monitor my program's actions and emulate these actions in my own application. Did I get right ?

Comment: Correct. You get it right.

Comment: Thank you. If you have any other suggestions for me to check out, could you please share them with me? If you know an example 3rd party program, please share it.